# Free VST Effects and Instruments

Tags: free, plugin, effects, instruments

Hey guys, I'm Indian and I'm pretty cheap so I've never paid for plugins or VST instruments (yet) and I'm always on the look out for something free, so I thought I'd list some of the stuff that I've found and if you guy's have something that I haven't listed we can share links.

**Plugins:**

[Variety of Sound](http://varietyofsound.wordpress.com/vst-effects/): I found these plugins today and I'm not sure if anyone's used them before but I was so impressed by how good they look and sound, their **epicVerb** and **FerricTDS** are the best plugins I've heard out of my computer (I don't know how it compares to stuff like Waves and others though).

[Kjaerhus Audio Classic Series](http://www.acoustica.com/plugins/vst-directx.htm): I found these from DJ Laidback Luke he mentioned them in some weird studio tour in his home, These are pretty alright I like the **Auto-Filter**.

[ReaPlugs](http://www.reaper.fm/reaplugs/): I found these today as well but I haven't tried them yet, these are the plugins that are found in Cockos REAPER, I'm excited to try their **Multi-band Compressor** cause I've never really used one before.

[Molot](http://vladgsound.wordpress.com/plugins/molot/): This is a Russian **Compressor** which I haven't used yet to be honest but its looks great.

**Instruments:**

[Elektrostudio](http://www.elektrostudio.ovh.org/index2.php): These were first free synths that I had found, I really like the **Model Pro** its like a replica of the Moog Prodigy its pretty fun to play with.

[MinimogueVA](http://home.no/gunnare/index.htm): This is one more thing I found today, its a replica of the **Mini Moog** and its so much fun and sounds great too.

[Formant Classic](http://www.ftec-audio.com/formant-classic/): I found this synth last night and its pretty good, the guy who made it says that its good for learning how to use synths and stuff.

[DiscoDSP HighLife](http://www.discodsp.com/highlife/): I found this through the Game Audio Tutorial book and its so much fun, its a **Sampler**, I like to put in recordings of my brother farting and make melodies out of it lol.

[Vocov2](http://www.g200kg.com/en/software/vocov.html): This is a fun **Vocoder** which is another alternative I use to make music with my brother's farts.

[TS-808](http://tactilesounds.blogspot.com/p/tactile-synthesizers.html): Ohh snap this is another thing I found today, this is obviously a replica of the **Roland 808 Drum Machine**, I've only played around a little bit with this but from what I've heard so far its really good.

So anyway I hope this doesn't make me look like a super duper fantastical cheapo and also since I'm still a beginner in sound and can't really help many people on here, I hope at least these can help you guys.

Comment: That's an awesome list! Thanks so much! i do think we should have this under "community wiki" though. 

Answer (score 4):

[Soundhack](http://www.soundhack.com/) is a great place to find freeware plug ins.

Comment: Beat me to it. Probably the best freeware available. 

Answer (score 3):

dblue/Illformed has a bunch, mostly for glitchy/lo-fi type effects.

http://illformed.org/plugins/

They're not Stutter Edit or anything, but definitely usable if you're going in the non-organic sound design direction and want a few more options.

Comment: dblue glitch is wicked.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice you mentioned it here, I also added it into my list Glitch is really cool I found it somewhere else in some video tutorial though.

Answer (score 2):

I love DFX skidder.  Its free, intuitive and easy to use.  Great for pass-bys.

http://destroyfx.smartelectronix.com/

they have other plugs as well

Answer (score 2):

Adding on, but not all are available as VST

[Blue Cat Plugins](http://www.bluecataudio.com/Download/Home/) Bunch of pretty useful plugins

[Massey Plugins](http://www.masseyplugins.com/) only for ProTools though

[BX Cleansweep](http://www.brainworx-music.de/en/plugins/bx_cleansweep_v2)

[BX Solo](http://www.brainworx-music.de/en/plugins/bx_solo)

[iZoptope Vinyl](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/vinyl/)

Comment: yeah, the Blue Cat plugins are great. 

Answer (score 1):

AU not VST, but Micheal Norris' excellent Sound Magic Spectral Plug-Ins have done well for me.
http://www.michaelnorris.info/soundmagicspectral/index.html

I'm also fond of the Togu Audio Line stuff...
http://kunz.corrupt.ch/

Comment: Yeah I've used Togu's Vocoder its not too bad I prefer the one I listed though.

Answer (score 1):

http://plugins.gersic.com/index.php - great source for free plug-ing.

Answer (score 1):

uhm you guys know that kvraudio.com is the place to search for audio plugin effects and instruments .. right? the advanced "search" page is totally awesome .. just set it up to search for free stuff

Comment: Quite a few of these were found there.

Answer (score 0):

I like you already man :D

Answer (score 0):

Some big companies have free stuff too:

**Solid State Logic (SSL)** - http://solidstatelogic.com/music/section_free_plug-ins.asp

**Voxengo** - http://www.voxengo.com/group/free-vst-plugins/

**Sonalksis** - http://www.sonalksis.com/freeg.htm

**Camel Audio** - http://www.camelaudio.com/products.php

And if you have never tried **KVR** database I am recommending this search  http://www.kvraudio.com/q.php?search=1&pr[]=f

**PS: Do not forget your DAW plug-ins!!! Sometimes is much more better than mass of uselles free plug-ins..**

Answer (score 0):

This list has a lot of them:

[Best free VST 2014](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2014/12/29/free-vst-plugins-2014/)

I'm also fan of [Softube Saturation Knob](http://www.softube.com/index.php?id=satknob)

Answer (score 0):

Use the melda [MFreeEffectsBundle](https://www.meldaproduction.com/plugins/product.php?id=MFreeEffectsBundle) which has 42 plugins. Some of them are demos though but they are realy great

Also you can check [VST4Free](http://vst4free.com) for amazing free plugins. Some are really good

Comment: Why wasn't this here yet?